# Symfony 2.7 : EntityType - force no result in query builder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.7

I didn't find a post to resolve my problem, hope it is not a duplicate.

In a Symfony Form, I declared an *entity* field.

```
$form->add($builder->getFormFactory()->createNamed(
    'cert_folder_product_factory',
    new EntityMultipleType(),
    null,
    array(
        'label' => '',
        'mapped' => false,
        'class' => 'ProductsBundle:ProductFactory',
        'empty_value' => '',
        'auto_initialize' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'label_controls' => array('add' => 'Add Product', 'remove' => 'Remove Product'),
    )
));
```

I want this field at start to have an empty collection of entities because the collection is based on an other field value, so i don't put any *query_builder* param at declaration.

```
$form->add($builder->getFormFactory()->createNamed(
    'supplier_list',
    'entity',
    null,
    array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'label' => ' ',
        'class' => 'SuppliersBundle:Suppliers',
        'empty_value' => '',
        'auto_initialize' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'data' => $data->getSupplierProduct(),
        'query_builder' => function(\Ella\SuppliersBundle\Repository\SuppliersRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('q')->andWhere('q.is_delete = 0')->orderBy('q.name', 'asc');
        })  
    )
);
```

Once *supplier_list* field has a value, an AJAX query retrieves elements associated and populate the collection of the *cert_folder_product_factory* field.

In order to validate the Form at submission and as recommandated, I declared *PRE_SUBMIT* EventListener to populate the field collection and validates values selected by my users

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder, $container) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$data['supplier_list']) {
            return;
        }

        $supplierId = $data['supplier_list'];

        $form->add($builder->getFormFactory()->createNamed(
                'cert_folder_product_factory',
                new EntityMultipleType(),
                null,
                array(
                        'label' => '',
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'class' => 'ProductsBundle:ProductFactory',
                        'empty_value' => '',
                        'auto_initialize' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'label_controls' => array('add' => 'Add Product', 'remove' => 'Remove Product'),
                        'query_builder' => function(\Ella\ProductsBundle\Repository\ProductFactoryRepository $er) use ($supplierId) {
                            return $er->getProductBySupplier($supplierId);
                        },
                )
            )
        );
    });
```

Everything works fine once i have a value for *supplier_list* field and form submissions. But, as Symfony documentation explains for *query_builder*, default behaviour with query_builder param is to load all the entities, making loading time very very long for nothing.

My workaround is to force the load of one arbitrary entity

```
'query_builder' => function (\Ella\ProductsBundle\Repository\ProductFactoryRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('q')->setMaxResults(1);
}
```

But this solution is totally wrong, any proper way to force the entity collection to load 0 entity at first ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're trying to do an autocomplete form type?

Comment: If so, takes a look at this form type of EasyAdminBundle: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/8c4c36c94e4b4c3221c8a2b5895313c6838b10d9/src/Form/Type/EasyAdminAutocompleteType.php

Comment: Not sure about 2.7 but in 3.x you can pass `choices` to the form type which will override populating choices with results from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, the simple thing to do was to pass `null` as value of `$supplierId` parameter, no result will be retrieved (only works if you pass your value in the `setParameter()` of your querybuilder).

I also added a formModifier as described in https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-user-data to avoid the copy / paste of same field in the differents `EventListener`

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $supplierId = null, $productFactories = null) {
            $form->add('cert_folder_product_factory', new EntityMultipleType(),
                    array(
                        'label' => '',
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'class' => 'ProductsBundle:ProductFactory',
                        'empty_value' => '',
                        'auto_initialize' => false,
                        'required' => false,
                        'label_controls' => array('add' => 'Add Product', 'remove' => 'Remove Product'),
                        'query_builder' => function(\Ella\ProductsBundle\Repository\ProductFactoryRepository $er) use ($supplierId) {
                                return $er->getProductBySupplier($supplierId);
                        },
                        'data' => (count($productFactories) > 0) ? $productFactories : null,
                    )
            );
        };
```

In PRE_SET_DATA to declare the field

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier, $builder, $container) {
     $formModifier($form,
            ($data->getSupplierProduct()) ? $data->getSupplierProduct()->getId() : null,
            (count($data->getProductFactory())) ? $data->getProductFactory() : null
    );
}
```

Then in PRE_SUBMIT to validate form submission

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $formModifier($form,
                array_key_exists('supplier_list', $data) ? $data['supplier_list'] : null
        );
});
```